# C strncat function

Tags: c

someone know what is the problem in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 10
void printMessage(char str[]);

int main(void)
{
    char str[MAX_LEN] = "THANK ";
    char you = 'u';
    strncat(str, you, 1); // do not fix this line or the next one
    printMessage(str);
    return 0;
}
```

The error that I get is:

> strncat: this function or variable may be unsafe, consider using strnact_s in stead.

However, I want to use this function `strncat`.

Comment: I believe you got a ***warning***, not an ***error***.   A warning and an error are not the same thing.

Comment: Also, the 2nd parameter should be a `const char *` not a `char`.

Comment: Microsoft's C compiler warns that certain functions in the standard library are unsafe (meaning difficult to use correctly), and suggests alternatives. The warning does not necessarily suggest that there's anything wrong with your code.

Comment: i got an error and not warning and even if i try const char it's does not working

Comment: You can define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to turn off the notifications about the "safe" string function alternatives.

Comment: If you have `char you = 'u';`, the call should be `strncat(str, &you, 1);`.

Answer (score -1):

You probably got this error message:

```
Error C4996 'strncat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncat_s instead.
To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

To remove the warning you can put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the start of your code.

Furthermore this is wrong:

```
char you = 'u';
```

because the second parameter of `strncpy` is a pointer to char and not a char. Change it to:

```
char you[] = "u";
```

As an alternative you could also leave `char you = 'u'` and call `strncat` like this:

```
strncat(str, &you, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't wanna get the warning C4996 then tell Visual Studio that you don't want that warning.

You can do it in many ways.

Since I like portable C code and therefore I don't want to add #pragmas in my source files, I prefer telling Visual Studio to disable that specif warning.

Just disable warning C4996, as showed in the picture:

[image: disable: 4996]